# Accessing twitter using tornado.httpclient using proxy

Tags: python, proxy, tornado

I want to access Twitter from the terminal using `tornado.httpcilent`.

But Twitter is firewalled in my country. How can I access it through proxy?

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official documentation for tornado.httpclient](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html) contains examples how to use proxy.

You will need curl backend for proxy support. So install the prerequisites. Here's how to do that for Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl-dev librtmp-dev 
$ pip install tornado pycurl
```

Then try this code:

```
from tornado import httpclient, ioloop

config = {
    'proxy_host': 'YOUR_PROXY_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
    'proxy_port': 3128
}

httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure(
    "tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")

def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://twitter.com/",
    handle_request, **config)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Thanks!it works just fine. I really don't know there's a proxy option with tornado.httpclient.

Comment: Should warn, since lost 2 hours on this. Tornado support proxy only with Pycurl. And Pycurl support only 2.x Python branch. So, no proxy for Python 3.x