# Does tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient support using http proxy in Python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, python-requests

I have read the [AsyncHTTPClient](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient) document and not found how to use proxy through `AsyncHTTPClient` method.
So I want to know if there's a way to do so. My python version is 3.3.

I have found the [trequest](https://github.com/1stvamp/trequests) project but when I use `trequest.request` and yield http requests by adding proxies in the method, I found it doesn't work as I desire.
Is there a way to use `requests` in tornado asynchronously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tornado currently only supports proxies when configured to use curl_httpclient.  This was Python 2.x-only until recently, but it is now possible (with the latest versions of both tornado and pycurl) to use it on Python 3.  Just do `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")` when your program is starting up.

Comment: Thank you! And I've found [the specific usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016951/accessing-twitter-using-tornado-httpclient-using-proxy/12019906#12019906) :D